# Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ diagonalizable matrix with positive real eigenvalues. Prove that $A$ is invertible .

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to prove this but the most I can get is that the eigenvalues cannot be zero, and when I try to prove why the values cant be negative, that is where I get stuck. Can someone give me a valid proof so I can understand this?

Comment: Do you know that the diagonal form of a diagonalizable matrix consists of its eigenvalues? Or that $\det(A)$ is the product of the eigenvalues? Either of these facts would help.

Comment: You have that $A=CDC^{-1}$ where $C$ is a change of basis matrix (invertible) and $D$ is diagonal with all its diagonal elements non zero. You can prove that $D$ is then invertible and thus $A$ also is.

Comment: The question makes no sense. Why would you try to prove the eigenvalues can't be negative if you already know that they are positive? Anyway, a matrix is invertible if and only if $0$ is not its eigenvalue. (because $0$ being an eigenvalue exactly means that there is some nontrivial vector $v\ne 0$ such that $Av=0$)

Comment: I tried to proove by contradiction

Comment: @Ameji B. This is the only information I was given

Comment: Well clearly your knowledge doesn't exist in a vacuum. I'm asking if you are familiar with either of these facts. There's many directions in linear algebra so we can't give you a sufficient answer if we don't know your background knowledge

Comment: @AmejiB. Oh, I didn't understand the context of the question. I am essentially familiar with all of the definitions, Theorems, and Properties regarding the topics mentioned above. I just need a push so I can figure out how to prove this by contradiction, or some other method.

Comment: The thing that tripped me up is the fact that the det of a matrix only needs to be nonzero to be invertible and since the determinate of a diagonal matrix is the product of all its eigenvalues then it being positive or not shouldn't matter. But clearly, it does.

Comment: At some point in your class you should have been given a long list of things that are equivalent to a matrix being invertible. I'd suggest going through that list one by one and seeing if you can get traction with any of those equivalent conditions.

Comment: Sure, all you need is that they are non-zero. Being all positive certainly implies that they are all non-zero.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank You!